# Unable to kill spark application through spark-submit on spark standalone cluster with spark authentication and encryption enabled

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am not able to kill the spark application through spark submit command on spark standalone cluster with spark authentication and encryption enabled. Command-

```sh
bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill spark://host:7077 driver-20200728102235-0005.
```

````
Getting error: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.ClientApp$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.ClientApp$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:243)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.ClientApp.start(Client.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$.main(Client.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client.main(Client.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown challenge message.
        at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthRpcHandler.receive(AuthRpcHandler.java:109)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:180)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:103)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)```
````

Answer (score 0):

On you spark client, try to set this value: `-Dspark.authenticate=true -Dspark.network.crypto.enabled=true` inside the environment variables called `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`, `spark.executorEnv.JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and so on.

Also please check that your secret is stored inside the `spark.executorEnv._SPARK_AUTH_SECRET` environment variable.

If it doesn't work, I suggest adding your spark-submit configuration to this topic.